raspberry pi bluetooth not showing up on Mac
I have a bluetooth server that I wrote in python running on a Raspberry Pi Zero, and it works great. I can connect to it from my iPhone and I have python code that connects to it running on my Mac. The problem I have is that the device does not show up on my Mac settings. I know this is probably a Mac problem and not a Raspberry Pi issue, but if anyone has experience it and knows how to fix it, I'd appreciate it.

What "Mac settings" are you referring to?

I think iOS only has APIs for BLE and I suspect you have created a Bluetooth Classic server on the Raspberry Pi
